# Manage task with Gitlab inside WebStorm

Tags: gitlab, webstorm

In my previous office I know how to manage task with Redmine and PhpStorm.

Now I came with question how do I this with WebStorm and Gitlab. Seems I  already try to input valid server URL but it still reject. This is the screenshoot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, double check your url: itr is case sensitive.

Second, see [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000063484-GitLab-issue-tracking-setup-SOLVED):

> It seems that this is not an IntelliJ bug, but an expected behaviour due to long response times from `Gitlab` API.
>
> Go to `Preferences > Tools > Tasks` and increase the timeout time to 15000.

(See [issue IDEA-166992](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166992))

> For the record, to log in you should create a new Personal Access Token at https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens so that you don't have to use your account's private token or password.

The [OP Faris Rayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119946/faris-rayhan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579409/manage-task-with-gitlab-inside-webstorm/43579836#comment74801657_43579836):

> I use private token on this link [gitlab.com/profile/account](https://gitlab.com/profile/account) and it works.
> I also added maximum timeout time to be 15000 and server URL as `gitlab.com`.

Comment: I use private token on this link https://gitlab.com/profile/account and it works. I also added maximum timeout time to be 15000  and server URL as https://gitlab.com

Comment: @FarisRayhan Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.